# Boolean expressions, visitor pattern and.. stack overflow

Tags: c++, design-patterns, stack-overflow, visitor-pattern

Boolean expressions, visitor pattern and.. stack overflow

I have some kind of expression library than defines boolean expressions (something that can evaluate to true or false).
The code looks like this:

```
class ExpressionVisitor;

class Expression
{
public:
    virtual ~Expression() {}    
    virtual void Accept(ExpressionVisitor &visitor) = 0;
    //.. other methods
    
}

class ConstantExpression : public Expression
{
public:
    ConstantExpression(bool val) : m_val(val){}
    void Accept(ExpressionVisitor &visitor) override { visitor.VisitConstantExpression(this); }
    bool GetValue() const { return m_val; }
private:
    bool m_val;
}

class NotExpression : public Expression
{
public:
    NotExpression(Expression *pInnerExpression) : m_pInnerExpression(pInnerExpression) {}
    void Accept(ExpressionVisitor &visitor) override { visitor.VisitNotExpression(this); }
    Expression* GetInnerExpression() const { return m_pInnerExpression; }    
private:
    Expression *m_pInnerExpression;
}

class BinaryExpression : public Expression
{
public:
    AndExpression(Expression *pLeftExpression, Expression *pRightExpression) : m_pLeftExpression(pLeftExpression), m_pRightExpression(pRightExpression) {}
    Expression* GetLeftExpression() const { return m_pLeftExpression; }
    Expression* GetRightExpression() const { return m_pRightExpression; }
private:
    Expression m_pLeftExpression, m_pRightExpression;
}

class AndExpression : public BinaryExpression
{
public:
    AndExpression(Expression *pLeftExpression, Expression *pRightExpression) : BinaryExpression(pLeftExpression, pRightExpression) {}
    void Accept(ExpressionVisitor &visitor) override { visitor.VisitAndExpression(this); }
}

class OrExpression : public BinaryExpression
{
public:
    OrExpression(Expression *pLeftExpression, Expression *pRightExpression) : BinaryExpression(pLeftExpression, pRightExpression) {}
    void Accept(ExpressionVisitor &visitor) override { visitor.VisitOrExpression(this); }
}

class ExpressionVisitor
{
public:
    virtual ~ExpressionVisitor() {}
    void VisitConstantExpression(ConstantExpression*);
    void VisitNotExpression(NotExpression*);
    void VisitAndExpression(AndExpression*);
    void VisitOrExpression(OrExpression*);
}
```

Now to evalate an expression I have a concrete visitor:

```
class EvaluatorVisitor : public ExpressionVisitor
{
public:
    EvaluatorVisitor() : m_result(false){}
    
    bool GetResult() const { return m_result; }

    void VisitConstantExpression(ConstantExpression* pExpr)
    {
        m_result = pExpr->GetValue();
    }
    void VisitNotExpression(NotExpression* pExpr)
    {
        pExpr->GetInnerExpression()->Accept(this);
        auto innerResult = m_result;
        m_result = !innerResult;
    }
    void VisitAndExpression(AndExpression* pExpr)
    {
        pExpr->GetLeftExpression()->Accept(this);
        auto leftResult = m_result;
        pExpr->GetRightExpression()->Accept(this);
        auto rightResult = m_result;
        m_result = leftResult && rightResult;
    }
    void VisitOrExpression(OrExpression* pExpr)
    {
        pExpr->GetLeftExpression()->Accept(this);
        auto leftResult = m_result;
        pExpr->GetRightExpression()->Accept(this);
        auto rightResult = m_result;
        m_result = leftResult || rightResult;
    }
    
private:
    bool m_result;
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
EvaluatorVisitor evaluator;
Expression *pExpr = ...;
pExpr->Accept(&evaluator);
bool result = evaluator.GetResult();
```

Now for really large (deep) expressions that contains a lot of binary expressions, I get a stack overflow
because the EvaluatorVisitor is inherently recursive (because of the Accept() call).
How do I solve this (besides the obvious 'increase the stack size')?

EDIT1:
I'm pretty sure that I don't have an infinite recursion.
The code above is a simplified version of my code to show the problem.
The problem arises because between each Accept() call in the visitor each function create some state to produce a result.

I think the problem can be summarized using another example:

```
struct Node 
{
    T Value;
    Node* Next;
}

T ComputeAllResult(Node *n)
{
    if (!n) return {};

    auto result1 = ProduceResult(n.Value); <--- state for this stack frame
    auto result2 = ComputeAllResult(n.Next);
    
    return CombineResults(result1, result2);
}
```

this will overflow the stack when the linked-list is really large *AND* the state is large (typeof(T))

Comment: How large is 'really large'. On the face of it I'd be worried about an infinite recursion and trying to solve the bug that caused that to happen.

Comment: You could use trampoline-style in your visitor interface, but the more pressing concern is whether you have infinite recursion as that seems a lot more likely than overflowing the stack due to a deep expression structure.

Comment: I replied in the question (see EDIT1)

Comment: First thing to do is to prove that you don't have an infinite recursion.  Make the problem go away by using a larger stack.  Probably you actually *do* have an infinite recursion, unless you're purposely creating unrealistically deep expressions.

Answer (score -1):

This library is terrible. One of those made during OOP craze.

Instead of this crappy class-based approach that overflows the callstack - simply make a `std::variant` of all types that you use (I'd suggest `enum` but some of the types contain data instead of orders). You don't need the abstract class expression - just make a couple of simple switch cases to deal with the variations.

This way you can process everything in a while-loop instead of recursion. To do that you store your location in the expression via a `std::stack` of the variant plus current value. This way even expression with huge depth can be processed with ease as it is much harder to overflow `std::stack`.

Comment: @user19668335 well... no. Expression is rigid and straightforward. OOP has its purpose but the library you have abuses it badly. It very inefficient due overuse of virtual functions for simple operations and recursion. Recursion is over taught in university courses which leads to great many graduates write terrible code. Not to mention other issues- that you can't even properly check if there are any loops inside the expression.